# Mangal Graha Dev Temples in India and their significance

Tags: astrology

I learned that there are only 2 temples of Mangal Graha Devata in India, one at Ujjain and the second at Amalner.

Devotees facing problems of life due to the adverse placement of Mangal Graha in their or their loved ones' kundlis, visit these Mangal Graha Deva temples for rectification or amelioration of their problems.

Can anybody who has visited them or who has faced problems of life due to the adverse placement of Mangal Graha in their or their loved ones' kundlis, or those who are well informed in this matter, answer the following queries?

**Queries:**

- 1. Is there a mention of any of these temples and related anecdotes in any of the scriptures?
- 2. Are there any more Mangal Graha Devata temples in India?
- 3. Are all the temples related to only resolving problems of life due to the adverse placement of Mangal Graha in one's kundli?
- 4. Does each temple have a separate significance of its own other than resolving problems of life due to the adverse placement of Mangal Graha in one's kundli?
- 5. Is each temple of the Devata, significant in solving a particular problem arising due to a particular adverse placement of Mangal Graha in one's kundli?

Please throw some light on this.

Comment: The supposed temple dedicated to Angaraka in Kolkata is actually a Shiva temple built rather recently by Hindi-speaking people. As a resident of north Kolkata, I assure you that no temple dedicated to Mangala exists here or elsewhere in Bengal. The temple you erroneously mentioned isn't even counted amongst the famous temples of Kolkata by any criteria (architectural, religious, associative or historical significance).

Comment: Thanks @অনু for the info. I got the info of 3 temples from google search for Mangal Graha temples. I forgot to search for the other name Angaraka. Now I did and found another temple associated but not dedicated to Mangal Dev, in Vaitheeswaran Koil, Tamilnadu. The temple is basically dedicated to Shiva. (Wikipedia-Vaitheeswaran is believed to preside over Angarakan in the temple. Along with Angarakan, Sambathi, Jatayu and Surya deva are believed to have worshipped Vaitheeswaran at this temple.) May be the Kolkata temple dedicated to Shiva is also similarly associated with Mangala Graha Devata.

Comment: @অনু. So that brings the number of temples of Mangala Graha Devata to 2. I have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: What about the Temple at Ujjain? Is it a temple dedicated to Mangala Graha Dev or is it assosiated with Mangal Graha Devata just like the Temples at Kolkata and Tamilnadu as discussed above? Anybody please?

Comment: I just found that the idol at the Mangalnath temple of Ujjain is actually a Shiv ling and not that of Mangal Graha Devata. The idol that is worshiped at Amalner, Maharashtra is that of the Mangal Graha Devata, red in colour. So does that make, Amalner temple the only temple dedicated to Mangala Graha Devata?